# Regex that captures a group with a positive lookahead but doesn't match a pattern

Tags: python, regex

Using regex (Python) I want to capture a group `\d-.+?` that is immediately followed by another pattern `\sLEFT|\sRIGHT|\sUP`.

Here is my test set (from http://nflsavant.com/about.php):

```
(9:03) (SHOTGUN) 30-J.RICHARD LEFT GUARD PUSHED OB AT MIA 9 FOR 18 YARDS (29-BR.JONES; 21-E.ROWE).
(1:06) 69-R.HILL REPORTED IN AS ELIGIBLE.  33-D.COOK LEFT GUARD TO NO 4 FOR -3 YARDS (56-D.DAVIS; 93-D.ONYEMATA).
(3:34) (SHOTGUN) 28-R.FREEMAN LEFT TACKLE TO LAC 37 FOR 6 YARDS (56-K.MURRAY JR.).
(1:19) 22-L.PERINE UP THE MIDDLE TO CLE 43 FOR 2 YARDS (54-O.VERNON; 51-M.WILSON).
```

My best attempt is `(\d*-.+?)(?=\sLEFT|\sRIGHT|\sUP)`, which works unless other characters appear between a matching capture group and my positive lookahead. In the second line of my test set this expression captures "69-R.HILL REPORTED IN AS ELIGIBLE.  33-D.COOK." instead of the desired "33-D.COOK".

My inputs are also saved on regex101, here: https://regex101.com/r/tEyuiJ/1

How can I modify (or completely rewrite) my regex to only capture the group immediately followed by my exact positive lookahead with no extra characters between?

Comment: "_Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!_" is pretty much like asking ['Can somebody help me?', which is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: If you don't want to skip over digits, use `\D` e.g. [`\b(\d+-\D+?)\s(?:LEFT|RIGHT|UP)`](https://regex101.com/r/dXPxM9/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent skipping over digits, use `\D` [non-digit](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#chars) (upper is *negated* `\d`).

```
\b(\d+-\D+?)\s(?:LEFT|RIGHT|UP)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dXPxM9/1)

---

Further added a [word boundary](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html) and changed the *lookahead* to a [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap).

Answer (score 3):

If you want a capture group without any lookarounds:

```
\b(\d+-\S*)\s(?:LEFT|RIGHT|UP)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d+-\S*)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits `-` and optional non whitespace characters
- `\s` Match a single whitespace character
- `(?:LEFT|RIGHT|UP)` Match any of the alternatives
- `\b` A word boundary

See the capture group value on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LMvvEm/1).

Answer (score 2):

This is why you should be careful about using `.` to match anything and everything unless it's absolutely necessary. From the example you provided, it appears that what you're actually wanting to capture contains no spaces, thus we could utilize a negative character class `[^\s]` or alternatively more precisely `[\w.]`, with either case using a `*` quantifier.

Your end result would look like `"(\d*-[\w.]*)(?=\sLEFT|\sRIGHT|\sUP)"gm`. And of course, when `.` is within the character class it's treated as a literal string - so it's not required to be escaped.

See it live at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OwJwwS/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\b\d+-[^\r \n]+(?= +(?:LEFT|RIGHT|UP)\b)
```

`\b\d+-[^\r \n]+`

- `\b` word boundary to ignore things like `foo30-J.RICHARD`
- `\d+` match one or more digit.
- `-` match a literal `-`.
- `[^\r \n]+` match on or more character except `\r`, `\n` and a literal space  . Excluding `\r` and `\n` helps us not to cross newlines, and that is why `\s` is not used(i.e., it matches `\r` and `\n` too)

`(?= +(?:LEFT|RIGHT|UP)\b)` Using positive lookahead.

- `+` Ensure there is one or more literal space  .
- `(?:LEFT|RIGHT|UP)\b` using non-caputring group, ensure our previous space   followed by one of these words `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `UP`. `\b` word boundary to ignore things like `RIGHTfoo` or `LEFTbar`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ftvCwJ/1)